# How to return row value if is null in String.Join

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, return

In my View I have this string join.

```
@String.Join(",", new userDbEntities().ShortCutsTables
      .Where(rt => rt.ShortCut == row1.MsgT.FirstOrDefault()).Select(r => r.OpisSlo))
```

Now this work fine, but, If I do not have shortcut that match in row1.MsgT it returns empty value. How to create if sentece here, so If there is no match, just return row1.MsgT.FirstOrDefault() and not null.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@String.Join(",", (new userDbEntities().ShortCutsTables
  .Where(rt => rt.ShortCut == row1.MsgT.FirstOrDefault()).Count() == 0 ? new List<string>{row1.MsgT.FirstOrDefault())} : new userDbEntities().ShortCutsTables
  .Where(rt => rt.ShortCut == row1.MsgT.FirstOrDefault()).Select(r => r.OpisSlo)))
```

You break off your original expression after the `Where` clause. If there is no match, the count of elements is 0 and you instead pass it `row1.MsgT.FirstOrDefault()`. Note that I am instantiating a `List<string>` with this value because `Where` returns an `IEnumerable`, so that both values in the ternary operator are compatible.